# Your query is syntactically correct but returned no results

Tags: influxdb, chronograf

Your query is syntactically correct but returned no results

```
SELECT mean("tup_inserted") AS "mean_tup_inserted" 
FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."postgresql" 
WHERE time > '2018-10-04T13:08:00.000Z' 
AND time < '2018-10-04T13:08:00.000Z' 
AND "db"='db_sige_mes_2018'
GROUP BY time(:interval:) FILL(null)
```

Comment: Your datetimes are identical, what datetime is going to be greater than *and* less then the same datetime?

Comment: ok, I noticed and fix it in this way

SELECT mean ("tup_inserted") AS "mean_tup_inserted" FROM "telegraf". "Autogen". "Postgresql" WHERE time> '2018-10-02' AND time <'2018-10-04' AND "db" = 'db_sige_mes_2018 'GROUP BY time (: interval :) FILL (null)

but apparently it's like I'm not collecting the information from the bd postgres server